# URL with special characters when searched not working in ElasticSearch 5.2.2

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not able to search URL's which contains special characters like 
http://example.sample.com/guide/Analyzers_Terms_and_Analysis_%28ABC%29_Guide

Suppose I have indexed 4 noteText

1) `http://example.sample.com/guide/Analyzers_Terms_and_Analysis_%28ABC%29_Guide`

2) `example`

3) `Terms`

4) `Analysis`

Expected Result - When I search with full URL option (1) it should output me the exact result of URL only and not with partial search with other indexed values like `example`, `Terms`, `Analysis`.

Search Query are -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "http://example.sample.com/guide/Analyzers_Terms_and_Analysis_%28ABC%29_Guide",
                "fields": [
                  "noteText.ngrammed"
                ],
                "analyzer": "match_phrase_search"
              }
            },
            "boost": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "http://example.sample.com/guide/Analyzers_Terms_and_Analysis_%28ABC%29_Guide",
            "fields": [
              "noteText.ngrammed"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My mappings are

```
{
  "properties": {
    "userId": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "noteText": {
      "analyzer": "match_phrase",
      "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "ngrammed": {
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index Settings -

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "my_ngram": {
            "type": "nGram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 50
          }
        },
        "char_filter": {
          "whitespace_mapping": {
            "mappings": [
              "\\u00A0=>\\u0020"
            ],
            "type": "mapping"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [
              "whitespace_mapping"
            ],
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "stop",
              "my_ngram",
              "kstem"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          },
          "default_search": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [
              "whitespace_mapping"
            ],
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "kstem"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          },
          "match_phrase": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [
              "whitespace_mapping"
            ],
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          },
          "match_phrase_search": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [
              "whitespace_mapping"
            ],
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "stop"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to perform an exact search on the url field, it shouldn't be **analyzed** by elasticsearch while indexing the document. You can use the [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) to index the whole value as one big term. You can also change the default analyzer to be of type keyword by editing the elasticsearch.yml file to include the following:

```
index.analysis.analyzer.default.type: keyword
```

Comment: Updated index settings in my question - Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Changed the search query to resolve the issue :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "constant_score": {
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "http\\:\\/\\/example.sample.com\\/guide\\/Analyzers_Terms_and_Analysis_%28ABC%29_Guide",
                    "fields": [
                      "noteText"
                    ],
                    "analyzer": "match_phrase_search"
                  }
                },
                "boost": 5
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "http\\:\\/\\/example.sample.com\\/guide\\/Analyzers_Terms_and_Analysis_%28ABC%29_Guide",
                "fields": [
                  "noteText.ngrammed"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "require_field_match": true,
    "fields": {
      "noteText": {},
      "noteText.ngrammed": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 100,
    "number_of_fragments": 3
  }
}
```